# Differentiating an integral with variable as a limit

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

I want to differentiate the following function with respect to $x$: $$G(x) = \int_{0}^{x} (x-y)^nf(y)dy$$
I know how to solve the integral using the Leibniz rule, it is in the exact form which the formula requires. But the thing is that the course I am doing is fairly rigorous and hence it is not allowed to use results without proof. I feel that this can be calculated by using the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I haven't been able to find proof. Any help is appreciated. The original question is :

> Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function on $[0,\infty)$, and define the sequence of functions on $[0,\infty)$
> \begin{split} F_0(x)&=\int_0^x f(y) dy,\\ F_1(x)&=\int_0^x (x-y )f(y) dy,\\  \dots \dots \\  F_n(x)&=\frac{1}{n!} \int_0^x  (x-y)^nf(y) dy\\
> \dots \dots \end{split}
>
> Verify that $F'_n=F_{n-1}$, $F_{n}^{(n+1)}=f$, and the first $n$
> derivatives of $F_n$ vanish at $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
(x-y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}x^k(-y)^{n-k},
$$
we have
$$
G(x)=\int_0^x(x-y)^nf(y)dy=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}x^k\int_0^x (-y)^{n-k}f(y)dy.
$$
Computing the derivative of $G$, we get
\begin{eqnarray}
G'(x) &=&\sum_{k=1}^n{n \choose k}kx^{k-1}\int_0^x (-y)^{n-k}f(y)dy\cr
&&+\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}x^k(-x)^{n-k}f(x)\cr
&=&\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}x^{k-1}\int_0^x (-y)^{n-k}f(y)dy\cr
&&+f(x)\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}x^k(-x)^{n-k}\cr
&=& \sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}x^{k-1}\int_0^x (-y)^{n-k}f(y)dy\cr
&&+f(x)\cdot(x-x)^n \cr
&=&\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{p!(n-1-p)!}x^{p}\int_0^x (-y)^{n-p-1}f(y)dy+f(x)\cdot0\cr
&=&n\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{p!(n-1-p)!}x^{p}\int_0^x (-y)^{n-1-p}f(y)dy\cr
&=&n\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose p}x^{p}\int_0^x (-y)^{n-1-p}f(y)dy\cr
&=&n\int_0^x\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose p}x^{p} (-y)^{n-1-p}f(y)dy\cr
&=&n\int_0^x(x-y)^{n-1}f(y)dy
\end{eqnarray}